# Remove falsy values in object

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I'm trying to loop all the properties in an object and remove everything that are falsy, then return the object that was passed in using `delete`. Obviously I am doing something wrong... This is the code that I wrote so far.

```
var obj = {
  a: undefined,
  b: "banana",
  c: 0,
  d: false,
  e: "",
  f: "apple",
  g: 23
}

var truthy = function (obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
  if (obj[i] === null || obj[i] === undefined) {
  delete obj[i];
  }
 } return obj;
}
```

This is the actual question:
Make a function that takes in an object, loops through all its properties, and removes any that are falsy. Then return the object that was passed in. (hint: delete)

Comment: This does not remove `false` for instance, is that not considered "falsy" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Returning the object is redundant because you're modifying the object that was passed in. If you want to return a new object with properties filtered out, make a new object in the function and copy the properties you want to leave in into it.
2. Your definition of "falsy" isn't exactly in line with JavaScript's. If you want the same "falsy" as everywhere else, just say `if (!obj[i])`. Assuming that's what you want of course, but not considering `false` "falsy" is a bit silly.

What was your actual problem though?

Comment: This is the actual question: Make a function that takes in an object, loops through all its properties, and removes any that are falsy. Then return the object that was passed in. (hint: delete)

Comment: In that case it looks like your code is pretty much correct except maybe the definition of "falsy". For belt and braces you could also prevent values in the prototype chain from being processed (`hasOwnProperty`)

Comment: @wildcrazy - sounds like homework! Anyway, this answers that, it's as easy as doing `if (!obj[i])` -> https://jsfiddle.net/jrxck4yp/

Comment: Who considers `!false` to not be falsy? `false` is falsy and hence `!false` is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do `_.pickBy(obj, _.identity);` it will return object with only truthy values

Answer (score 0):

demo here:

```js
var obj = {
  a: undefined,
  b: "banana",
  c: 0,
  d: false,
  e: "",
  f: "apple",
  g: 23
}

var truthy = function (obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (!obj[i]) {
      delete obj[i];
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
console.log(truthy(obj));
```

because you use `===` so `null` (`''`) not equal to `false`, your code just remove key with `false` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, `falsy` means:

"
A falsy value is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context.

JavaScript uses type coercion in Boolean contexts.
"

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
if (document.all) [1]
```

So, if you want to delete all `falsy` values then, change the condition to `if (!obj[i])` which checks for falsy values and removes in next line.

refer:

1. JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk589h2s/
2. Article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP asked for, but related, and matches the question title. This deletes all falsy values, **but returns a new object**, instead of mutating the existing. This is what I generally use, if I don't need recursion.

```
const removeFalsy = (o: object) => {
    return Object.entries(o).reduce((a,[k,v]) => ( !v ? a : (a[k]=v, a)), {})
}
```

Might be useful for people stumbling on this answer, and requiring exactly this.